# Vb.Net Child Class sending Events to Parent Class

Tags: events, collections, parent-child, vb.net-2010

I have a class that is used to handle ItemList based objects and is bound to the controls on WPF.  When a user selects a value, I can see that in the class, but I need to send an event to the parent viewmodel class that the selection has changed, as the parent is handling all the other control updates.  I will have different parent class types, so declaring the parent as a specific type in the child is not possible.  An event appears to be what I need, but as a newbie and only somewhat familiar with VB, I have not been able to follow any of the examples dealing with either routedevents or delegates.  I have another similar case where I have an observable collection of fields that is mapped by individual collection row reference to a XAML grid, and I need to know at the parent level when one of the collection field classes has a value change (I see the change in the class setters).  Again, some sort of event is needed to notify the parent of the change.
I need to see exactly what I should put in both the parent and the child classes to register and call the events and I need it in VB (using .net4).  Any descriptive notes would be greatly appreciated.  I know this may be simple, but I am neck deep in the swamp trying to read the map.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, Finally found this site, which along with some stuff I picked up off MSDN got things straight. [link](http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/tip/Put-VBNET-events-in-the-hands-of-AddHandler?ShortReg=1&mboxConv=searchWinDevelopment_RegActivate_Submit&)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered myself.  Be nice if MSDN help dealt with collections on events.

Comment: It would be helpful to other people if you posted the answer